# Material on Three.js planes don't match lighting

Tags: javascript, three.js

I've created a shape in Three.Js by merging a curved plane and 2 flat planes. I've used MeshLambertMaterial for the material. The vertical plane and curved plane join perfectly. However there is noticeable hard line where the horizontal plane joins with the curve. The lighting does not seem to align. I want the 3 planes to appear as one object with smooth shading. Am I doing something wrong?

[codepen](https://codepen.io/fatlinesofcode/pen/dZWxPm?editors=0010)

```
    addShape() {
                var radius =58, height=100, startAngle=THREE.Math.degToRad(0), endAngle=THREE.Math.degToRad(90), horizontalSegments=25, verticalSegments=25;
                var width = radius * 2 * Math.PI;
                var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(width, height, horizontalSegments, verticalSegments);
                var index = 0;

                for(var i=0; i<=verticalSegments; i++) {
                    for(var j=0; j<=horizontalSegments; j++) {
                        var angle = startAngle + (j/horizontalSegments)*(endAngle - startAngle);
                        plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(angle);
                        plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
                        index++;
                    }
                }
                var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xa2cddd, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
                var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
                var curve = new THREE.Mesh(plane, material);
                curve.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(-90)


                var plane1 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(height, height, horizontalSegments, verticalSegments);
                var side1 = new THREE.Mesh(plane1, material);
                side1.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(270)
                side1.position.z = radius;
                side1.position.x = -radius * 0.85;

                var plane2 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(height, height, 1, 1);
                var side2 = new THREE.Mesh(plane2);
                side2.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad(90)
                side2.position.x = radius * 1.0
                side2.position.z = -radius * 0.8;

                plane.mergeMesh(side1);
                plane.mergeMesh(side2);
                mesh.rotation.y = THREE.Math.degToRad(180);
                mesh.add(curve);
                this.mesh = mesh;
                this.scene.add(mesh);
            }
addLight() {
    let light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 200);
    light1.position.set(0, 20, 10);
    this.scene.add(light1);

    let light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    this.scene.add(light2);
  }
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're not updating your normals. Normals along the curve should be updated to point toward the center of the curve to achieve the effect you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you have to compute the vertex normals. Use `THREE.Geometry.computeVertexNormals` for this.
See [`THREE.Geometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry)

```
plane.computeVertexNormals();
```

Further you can simplify things, if you draw the [`THREE.PlaneGeometry`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/PlaneGeometry) in one band With this solution, you can choose the start angle and the end angle as you like, and the planes at the start and the end will always be able to connect seamlessly to the curved part:

```
var radius = 58, height = 100,
    startAngle = THREE.Math.degToRad(-20),
    endAngle = THREE.Math.degToRad(110),
    horSegs = 25, vertSegs = 25,
    startLen = 100, endLen = 100;
var width = startLen + endLen + radius * (endAngle-startAngle);
var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width, height, horSegs+2, vertSegs);

var index = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= vertSegs; i++) {
  plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(startAngle) + startLen * Math.sin(startAngle);
  plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(startAngle) - startLen * Math.cos(startAngle);
  index++;
  for (var j = 0; j <= horSegs; j++) {
    var angle = startAngle + j / horSegs * (endAngle - startAngle);
    plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(angle);
    plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
    index++;
  }
  plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(endAngle) - endLen * Math.sin(endAngle);
  plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(endAngle) + endLen * Math.cos(endAngle);
  index++;
}
plane.computeVertexNormals();
```

See the code snippet:

```js
class World {
  constructor() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0x000000);
    document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);
    this.resize();

    // this.addCube();
    this.addShape();
    this.addLight();

    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize.bind(this));
  }

  update() {
    if (this.cube) this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01;
    if (this.mesh) this.mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
  }

  addLight() {
    let light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 200);
    light1.position.set(0, 20, 10);
    this.scene.add(light1);

    let light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040); // soft white light
    this.scene.add(light2);
  }

  
  addShape() {
    var radius = 58, height = 100,
        startAngle = THREE.Math.degToRad(-20),
        endAngle = THREE.Math.degToRad(110),
        horSegs = 25, vertSegs = 25,
        startLen = 100, endLen = 100;
    var width = startLen + endLen + radius * (endAngle-startAngle);
    var plane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( width, height, horSegs+2, vertSegs);
    
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i <= vertSegs; i++) {
      plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(startAngle) + startLen * Math.sin(startAngle);
      plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(startAngle) - startLen * Math.cos(startAngle);
      index++;
      for (var j = 0; j <= horSegs; j++) {
        var angle = startAngle + j / horSegs * (endAngle - startAngle);
        plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(angle);
        plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(angle);
        index++;
      }
      plane.vertices[index].z = radius * Math.cos(endAngle) - endLen * Math.sin(endAngle);
      plane.vertices[index].x = radius * Math.sin(endAngle) + endLen * Math.cos(endAngle);
      index++;
    }
    plane.computeVertexNormals();

    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
      color: 0xa2cddd,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
    });
    
    var mesh = new THREE.Object3D();
    var curve = new THREE.Mesh(plane, material);
    curve.rotation.z = THREE.Math.degToRad(-90);

    mesh.add(curve);
    this.mesh = mesh;
    this.scene.add(mesh);
  }

  render() {
    this.update();
    requestAnimationFrame(this.render.bind(this));
    this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
  }

  resize() {
    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      75,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      0.1,
      1000
    );

    this.camera.position.z = 200;

    this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }
}

var _w = new World();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
```